# Javascript: How to access properties and method of IIFE

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I have this code and wondering how can we access properties and method of IIFE

```
var app = (function () {
    function app() {
        this.name = 'fasf';
    }
    app.prototype.greeting = function () {
        this.a = 'hello world';
        console.log(name);
        window.alert('hello world');
    };
    app.prototype.sayhello = function () {
        var j = 't';
        console.log(this.a);
    };
    return app;
}());
```

also about this piece of code

```
var t = (function greet(name){
     name = name || 'enter your name'
     console.log('Hello ' + name);
})();
```

Comment: What do you mean by properties and methods of IIFE? IIFE is a function which is immediately invoked, wouhich properties and methods are you talking about.

Comment: An IEFE has no properties and methods. If at all, it has a return value, like `app` in your first snippet.

Answer (score 4):

With the code you have, you can just do this:

```
// create an instance of the app object
var a = new app();
// call methods on it
a.greeting();
a.sayhello();
```

Your IIFE returns the internal `app` constructor function and then assigns that to a variable named `app`.  So you can then do `new app()` to create an instance of that object.  Once you create an instance of that object, you can then call any of the methods on the prototype.

---

In your second IIFE, nothing is returned from the IIFE so `t` is undefined.

---

The IIFE itself does not have properties and methods.  That's just an immediately invoked function expression.  In your first one, it returns a constructor function which is then assigned to a variable so that variable can be used to create objects with that constructor function.  There are no properties or methods of the IIFE itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way the IIFE pattern works is that you use local variables for the stuff you want to keep private. Local variables are are only visible inside the function they were defined in they cannot be read or written from anywhere else in the program.

If you want to expose things inside the IIFE outside the IIFE one way to do it is via the return value of the immediately-invoked function:

```
var stuff = (function(){

    // These variables and functions are not
    // visible from the outside:

    var myvar1 = "Hello";
    var myvar2 = "World";

    var func1(){
        return myvar1 + " " + myvar2;
    }

    // But we can return a record that contains a
    // reference to our private functions, making them
    // visible outside this block.
    return {
       thefunc: func1
    }

}());

//Now we can call the "thefunc" function we exported
console.log( stuff.thefunc() );
```

I made sure to not repeat any variable names to avoid confusion.

In your first example, there isn't much of a point to using the IIFE pattern since there are no local variables that you are making private. You could have just defined the `app` function outside the IIFE and it would have worked the same.

The second case could have been written more clearly by putting the function in a separate line:

```
function greet(name){
     name = name || 'enter your name'
  console.log('Hello ' + name);
}
var t = greet();
```

Not only is it a bit weird to immediately invoke a named function but in your particular example, the "default argument value" pattern suggests that this function was designed to be called multiple times, sometimes passing the "name" argument and sometimes not passing it (in which case it defaults to the "enter your name" string.

Answer (score 0):

When using IIFE pattern (closure) you usually keep local variables and function private as properly mentions by hugomg's answer.

In case you need to selectively make public some specific property you could consider using "The Revealing Module Pattern" instead, [more info here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Below a simple example showing this pattern:

```js
var app = (function () {
 
        var privateVar = 'hello world';
 
        function sayhelloPrivate() {
             console.log(privateVar);
        }
 
        function sayhelloPublic() {
            console.log(privateVar);
        }
 
        // reveal public pointers to
        // private functions and properties
 
       return {
            sayhello : sayhelloPublic 
        };

    })();
 
app.sayhello();
//app.sayhelloPrivate(); this will not work as function is private and not visible outside module
```